# SNMP MIB notification's object references refer to undefined symbols, causing error. Should I edit?

Tags: compiler-errors, snmp, mib

I'm trying to manually edit a .mib file because when I try loading it into our NMS, it fails to load, and gives me a list of "undefined symbol" errors.

Almost all "undefined symbol" errors refer to objects that are in the OBJECTS clause of NOTIFICATION-TYPE modules.  Referring to the MIB code sample below, it looks like they are defining Traps with the prefix "adxv", but trying to refer to the objects with out the prefix.  For example, the first object referenced for each NOTIFICATION-TYPE is **trapSequenceID**, which is undefined in the MIB file, but **adxvTrapSequenceID** is defined.

I'm thinking this is a mistake by the vendor.  Would a possible solution be for me to append "adxv" to each of the objects being referenced in the notification definition?

If I did that, would I have to change the case of the first letter to a capital after where i append "adxv" ?

And if it does compile with the changes, would I expect that the agent in the machine I'm monitoring would process the traps/notifications and get requests correctly, since I presume it only is aware of the dotted OID format?

I'm new to MIBs and SMI, so not sure about a lot of this. Thanks

```
-- import clause for context --

IMPORTS
    Counter                      FROM RFC1155-SMI
    MODULE-IDENTITY, OBJECT-TYPE, IpAddress, enterprises, TimeTicks FROM SNMPv2-SMI;


-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Trap
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
adxvTrapAlarmSetClear OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX  INTEGER { set(0), clear(1)}
    MAX-ACCESS read-only
    STATUS current
    DESCRIPTION      "Alarm state. 0 is set, 1 is cleared"
    ::= { adxvEventTraps 2 }

adxvTrapSequenceID OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX Counter
    MAX-ACCESS read-only
    STATUS current
    DESCRIPTION      "Sequence ID"
    ::= { adxvEventTraps 11 }

adxvTrapSiteID OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX DisplayString (SIZE (0..20))
    MAX-ACCESS read-only
    STATUS current
    DESCRIPTION      "Trap SiteID is assigned to each unit"
    ::= { adxvEventTraps 3 }

adxvTrapDeviceModelName OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX DisplayString (SIZE (0..20))
    MAX-ACCESS read-only
    STATUS current
    DESCRIPTION      "Device model name"
    ::= { adxvEventTraps 4 }
```

---

### --  further examples Trap definitions excluded for brevity

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--   Trap Types
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

adxvHeartbeat  NOTIFICATION-TYPE
             OBJECTS   { trapSequenceID,trapTimeStamp,trapSiteID,trapDeviceModelName,trapDeviceSerial,trapLatitude,trapLongitude,trapAlarmSetClear}
             STATUS  current
             DESCRIPTION "Heartbeat"
              ::= { adxvEventTraps 1 }
adxvSystemHalt  NOTIFICATION-TYPE
             OBJECTS   { trapSequenceID,trapTimeStamp,trapSiteID,trapDeviceModelName,trapDeviceSerial,trapDeviceID,trapDeviceDescription,trapSeverity,trapAlarmSetClear}
             STATUS  current
             DESCRIPTION "System Halt alarm indication.(Hardfail)"
              ::= { adxvEventTraps 25 }

adxvLinkFail  NOTIFICATION-TYPE
             OBJECTS   { trapSequenceID,trapTimeStamp,trapSiteID,trapDeviceModelName,trapDeviceSerial,trapDeviceID,trapDeviceDescription,trapSeverity,trapAlarmSetClear}
             STATUS  current
             DESCRIPTION "Link fail alarm indication.(Softfail)"
              ::= { adxvEventTraps 26 }

adxvOvertemperHardfail  NOTIFICATION-TYPE
             OBJECTS   { trapSequenceID,trapTimeStamp,trapSiteID,trapDeviceModelName,trapDeviceSerial,trapDeviceID,trapDeviceDescription,trapSeverity,trapAlarmSetClear}
             STATUS  current
             DESCRIPTION "Overtemperature alarm(Hardfail)"
              ::= { adxvEventTraps 27 }
```

Comment: Compiling a MIB document is going to fail if you don't have the dependencies (specified in `IMPORTS` section). Thus, the errors you mentioned can be expected. Please escalate to a senior guy in your team, or hire a consultant to assist. There is much more to check and a site like Stack Overflow cannot help much.

Comment: @LexLi I added the MIB's import clause, and you can see that those object aren't referred to.  BTW, There is no senior guy, I'm trying to learn.

Comment: MIBs have bugs all the time, even published ones. It seems this one you can fix easily by renaming the objects in the OBJECTS clause, and hope there are no others.